# Header text next to a picture formatting

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code:

```
<div class="contact">
<p class="size25">TOP 1% Realtors</p>

<p class="size16">32 years in real estate</p>

<p class="size16">Closed one home every 10 days in 2011 - 2012</p>

<p class="size16">Specializing in the 24/680 Corridor</p>

<p class="size16"><a href="mailto:example@aol.com">example@aol.com</a></p>

<p class="size25 phone">(510) 555.5555</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.contact p{
    float:right;
}
.contact{
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    width: 421px;
    height: 114px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -96px;
    margin-left: 519px;
    font-family: 'Marcellus', serif;
    font-weight:300;
    line-height: 12px;
}
.contact a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #AC872F;
}
.phone{color: #AC872F}
.size25{font-size:25px}
.size16{font-size:16px}
.size14{font-size:14px}
.size11{font-size:11px}
.size10{font-size:10px}
```

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK48P.jpg

I want the text on the right to be aligned right and each

on it's own line. Right now as you can see the email is not. This is also my first time using twitter bootstrap so if there is something that can help me please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `clear: both` to the `.contact p`. The `clear` attribute removes other elements in line with a floating element.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q4YdC/ (I've removed the div margin for visibility reasons)